# Make ComboBox accept only specific type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I currently have a ComboBox in my Windows Forms Application. In order to specify which values the ComboBox will contain, I set DataSource property of the ComboBox to some array so that ComboBox contains values from that array. I could also use `Items.Add()` to add new values to ComboBox. However, I want to make sure that ComboBox can be populated with objects of some specific type. So, if I have a class called X, then I want to make it so that only an array of type X can be used as a data source for the ComboBox. Right now, ComboBox accepts objects of type `System.Object`. How can I achieve it? Is there a property of ComboBox that I need to set to be equal to  my data type's name? Or is there an event that will check whether an object added to my ComboBox is of the needed type and will throw an exception if not?

I was thinking of creating a new class as a subtype of ComboBox, and overriding the `Add` method of `Items` property so that Add checks whether its argument is of the needed type (not sure if and how I can do it). Even if I do that, there are still other ways to add new values into ComboBox (`AddRange`, `CopyTo`, etc.), so I think there should be a more elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: The idea which you want is possible, but you want to be done by someone of us ? Please try to build this combobox and after that write if you have problems.

Comment: @mybirthname - No, I just wanted to know if I should override Add method of ComboBox.ObjectCollection, or if there is a more elegant way of doing this, since technically I would also need to override other methods that can add new  values to ComboBox, such as AddRange.

Comment: you cant hide or override `Items` to *only* accept your new type even if you inherit from it; but you could try wrapping it in a UserControl and expose a New Items Collection.  There would be a lot of code to emulate/mimic existing properties and collections though.  Of course, the CBo will already accept your specific type, juts not *only* that Type

Comment: I ask only because of my curious. Why you need to prevent using other types of this `combobox`? If you do something with Items in `combobox` events then you can add checking of item's type in every event handler you using... Or give a properly name for this control ´ComboBoxOfMyType´, then other programmers will notice that this combobox using some type.

Comment: @Fabio - It's a homework assignment, so I am required to do it this way. You mentioned even handlers - is there an event that will fire every time something is added to Items of ComboBox? If yes, then I could write an event handler that will throw an exception when it sees that an object of an incorrect type is present in ComboBox.Items.

Comment: Did you tried overloads `Item` property in derived class `ComboBoxCustomType`?

Comment: @Fabio - yeah, I did. I made another similar post on Stackoverflow that you can look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835441/deriving-from-combobox). I end up having an Items property in my derived comboBox (MyComboBox2.Items) and an items property in the original comboBox (base.Items). I am able to insert into MyComboBox2.Items with my own Add() method, but in this case my comboBox on the screen does not show what I added to MyComboBox2.Items. I am able to add to base.Items and have that displayed on the form, but I can't use my own Add() method in this case. Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide `Items` property by your
own `Items` property of custom type which taking as parameter original ItemsCollection

Example class for testing

```
public class Order
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    public Order() { }
    public Order(Int32 inID, string inReference)
    {
        this.ID = inID;
        this.Reference = (inReference == null) ? string.Empty : inReference;
    }

    //Very important 
    //Because ComboBox using .ToString method for showing Items in the list
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Reference;
    }

}
```

With next class I tried wrap ComboBox's items collection in own type. 
Where adding items must be concrete type
Here you can add other methods/properties you need (Remove)

```
public class ComboBoxList<TCustomType>
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection _baseList;

    public ComboBoxList(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection baseItems)
    {
        _baseList = baseItems;
    }

    public TCustomType this[Int32 index]
    {
        get { return (TCustomType)_baseList[index]; }
        set { _baseList[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(TCustomType item)
    {
        _baseList.Add(item);
    }

    public Int32 Count { get { return _baseList.Count; } }

}
```

Here custom combobox class derived from ComboBox
Added: generic type

```
public class ComboBoxCustomType<TCustomType> : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
    //Hide base.Items property by our wrapping class
    public new ComboBoxList<TCustomType> Items; 

    public ComboBoxCustomType() : base()
    {
        this.Items = new ComboBoxList<TCustomType>(base.Items);
    }

    public new TCustomType SelectedItem 
    { 
        get { return (TCustomType)base.SelectedItem; } 
    }
}
```

Next code used in the Form

```
private ComboBoxCustomType<Order> _cmbCustom;

//this method used in constructor of the Form
private void ComboBoxCustomType_Initialize()
{
    _cmbCustom = new ComboBoxCustomType<Order>();
    _cmbCustom.Location = new Point(100, 20);
    _cmbCustom.Visible = true;
    _cmbCustom.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    _cmbCustom.Items.Add(new Order(0, " - nothing - "));
    _cmbCustom.Items.Add(new Order(1, "One"));
    _cmbCustom.Items.Add(new Order(2, "Three"));
    _cmbCustom.Items.Add(new Order(3, "Four"));
    _cmbCustom.SelectedIndex = 0;
    this.Controls.Add(_cmbCustom);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this approach works quite well. I can add that ComboBoxList is not derived from ComboBox.ObjectCollection, so it does not contain other methods of ObjectCollection, such as AddRange or Remove. So, in order to truly simulate ComboBox functionality, one would have to implement all other missing methods the way you implemented Add().

Comment: You suggested adding this custom ComboBox to the Form by doing it programmatically (setting Location, Visible properties, etc.). I cannot see this kind of derived comboBox in toolbox for the form, since it uses generics. Is it possible to add this custom comboBox to form using toolbox instead of doing it programmatically?

Comment: Try change ComboBox using only your type, not generic

Comment: Yeah, it's just that I needed specifically generic comboBox in Visual Studio Designer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the type of item that the `ComboBox` can contain, you could try creating a new class derived form `ComboBox`, but you'd run into the problem that it still has the `ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items` property which would still accept any type! And (unfortunately for your idea of overriding) the `Add` method isn't virtual.

The only practical solution that I could think of would be to abstract the `ComboBox` somehow. If this isn't shared code, I would recommend just creating a method that you would use to add items to the `ComboBox`. Something like:

```
// NOTE: All items that are added to comboBox1 need to be of type `SomeType`.
private void AddItemToComboBox(SomeType item)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Any attempt to add a non-`SomeType` object to the `ComboBox` would be met with a compiler error. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to prevent someone from still adding a non-`SomeType` item to `ComboBox.Items` directly.

Again, if this isn't shared code, it shouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That's what I was thinking of as well. I am new to C#, so I don't know if this will work - can I make Items property of my derived ComboBox  private, so that Items can be accessed  only from within the AddItemToComboBox() method? I don't think it's possible though.
Another thing I was thinking about was to create a new (empty) implementation of get method of 'Items' property, but use the original get method of Items property while adding inside AddItemToComboBox() method. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding ComboBox (which wont work as stated in [itsme86's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25828581/1324033)) you could override usercontrol, add a combobox to this, and then only expose the elements that you wish to work with. Something similar to

```
public partial class MyComboBox<T> : UserControl where T: class
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Items
    {
        get { return comboBox1.Items.Cast<T>(); }
    }
}
```

Please note however that some pieces of automated software rely on access the the underlying controls however so this may cause some issues.

This approach never changes the `Items` of the combobox so they will still store as `objects` but when you access them, you are casting them to the correct type and only allowing them to be added of that type. You can create a new combobox via

```
 var myCB = new MyComboBox<ItemClass>();
```