# Deriving from ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inheritance, combobox

I need to derive a class from ComboBox and change its Items property. Here is my code:

```
public class MyComboBox2 : ComboBox
{
    private MyObjectCollection MyItems;

    public MyComboBox2()
    {
        MyItems = new MyObjectCollection(this);
    }

    //new public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items
    new public MyObjectCollection Items
    {
        get {
            return MyItems;
        }
    }


}

public class MyObjectCollection : ComboBox.ObjectCollection
{
    public MyObjectCollection(ComboBox Owner) : base(Owner)
    {

    }

    new public int Add(Object j)
    {
        base.Add(j);
        return 0;
    }


}
```

As you can see, I am creating a new class `MyComboBox2` derived from `ComboBox`. This class is supposed to have a new Items property, which would be of type `MyObjectCollection` rather than `ComboBox.ObjectCollection`. I have a comboBox called `myComboBox21` on the form of type `MyComboBox2`. When I want to add a new object to my ComboBox, I would execute code like this: `myComboBox21.Items.Add("text");`
In this case, I end up executing the `Add` method of `MyObjectCollection` that I implemented myself. However, the ComboBox on the form does not end up containing value 'text'. I am attaching screenshot of debugger showing ComboBox values. `MyComboBox21` contains `Items` Property (which does contain "text", as shown in screenshot "2.png"), and it contains `base.Items` (which does not contain "text" as shown in "1.png"). So, apparently, `MyComboBox21` contains its own `Items` property (which I can insert to), and its base class's `Items` property, which gets displayed in the Windows Form. What can I do so that I can successfully add to comboBox with my own method? Since my ComboBox has 2 Items properties, can I specify which Items property's values should be shown in ComboBox?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking very quickly on the code:

The original Item index is declared as

```
     virtual Object this[int index] {...}
```

Does the *new* keyword maybe be exchanged by *override* in your implementation in order to make the runtime pick the intended code?

Comment: Did you mean that I should have "override public MyObjectCollection Items" instead of "new public MyObjectCollection Items" ? In this case, I get this error: "'Inheritance.MyComboBox2.Items': type must be 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection' to match overridden member 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Items'" . Even if I change type of Items to ComboBox.ObjectCollection, I get this error: "'Inheritance.MyComboBox2.Items.get': cannot override inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Items.get' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override"

Comment: Also, which Item index did you mean? Item is declared as "public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items { get; }" I don't think I can override it because it's not abstract or virtual.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I looked more into the problem, but unfortunately was not able to solve it. I found that hiding Combobox.Items does not really do anything for the combobox's behaviour because the internal code mostly uses its own private field rather than this property (http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox@cs/1305376/ComboBox@cs). It really seems to not be meant to be subclassed. Sorry, I have no answer to your problem.